# get items between do two date REST API

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, rest

can i get the list of items between two date like ?

```
var startDate.
var EndDate. 

var queryGetDiscussion = "?$Date between(startDate, EndDate) ";
```

Or using LT and GT.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you are asking about the SP2013 REST API.

Yes, but you would have to perform a few more conversions/comparisions like day(), month(), year() manually.

The oData Query Operators supported by SharePoint REST Api are listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx